# core pool size 0 and unbounded linkedblockingqueue

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi i am new to java and learning about concurrency. I saw the following code below. I ran the code and noticed only 1 thread is being used even though i concurrently submmited 100 task. What does it mean for corepoolsize = 0 with LinkedBlockedQueue (unbounded) and my maxpool is 120. thanks.

```
public static ThreadPoolExecutor generatetThreadPool() {

    ThreadFactory factory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("thread-%d")
        .build();
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 120, 3, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(), factory);
  }
```

Comment: That code doesn't submit any tasks.

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc for `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
corePoolSize – the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle,
    unless allowCoreThreadTimeOut is set
```

So when `corePoolSize` is zero, threads will terminate when `keepAliveTime` passes, and no new threads will be created to replace them until needed.